# How to start Redis with specific hostname

Tags: node.js, redis

My node app has this config:

```
const client = redis.createClient({ host: 'cache' });
```

When I launch it I get this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN cache
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:67:26) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'cache'
}
```

How do I specify 'cache' as my Redis hostname?

(note, this works fine using Docker, but I'm trying to test locally without Docker)

Comment: Is redis running on your local setup? That would make the hostname as 127.0.0.1
If not you need to find out the hostname of the server on which redis is running

Answer (score 0):

That's depends of your OS, but you can edit the hosts file to do it.

on Ubuntu, for exemplo:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
redis_ip        cache
```

if redis is running on your local machine:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
    
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       cache
```